# Pass js var through query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parameter-passing

I need to pass a js variable through out all pages where at the end of navigation, i need to summarize the total from all page and display the value.
Here is my JS code:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=q1]').click(function() {
      var selectedValue = $(this).val(); 
      if($(this).val() == "A3") 
      var count=1;
      else
      var count=0;
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form name="login" action=“page2.html" method="post">
    <section class="heading">
     <p><strong>Test1</strong></p>
    </section>
    <p class="pstyle">1st page</p>
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1A1" required value="A1" />
                Topic1
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left: 30px;">
                <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1A2" required value="A2"/>
                Topic2
            </td>
        </tr><br>
        <tr style="height: 77px;">
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1A3" required value="A3"/>
                Topic3  
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left: 30px;">
                <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1A4" required value="A4"/>
                Topic4          
            </td><br>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="Submit" value=“Next “Page style="font-size: 40px;"/>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left: 30px;">
                <input type="Submit" value="Cancel" style="font-size: 40px;"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>        
</form>
```

Please let me know how I can pass the variable "Count" to my another page. I am able to implement this with local storage but I need to pass it using query string. Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: If you need to use a query string, why not use a query string?  I think using localStorage is cleaner, anyway.  Your `action` attribute also contains a smart quote, so be careful there.

Comment: I agree with @ScottKaye, it's cleaner to use `window.localStorage` and avoid unnecessary URL lengthening.

Comment: What is the actual sequence of events here?  Are you submitting this form to a server and then you want the page that is returned form the form submission to have the properly set `count` variable?  If so, where is your server code because that's what is generated the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> php include

to include js code in your files from start. So whenever you will modify your code, it will maintain its versatility in all files.